# How can I terminate HTTPS traffic to elb and the container is running HTTP (fargate)

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, aws-fargate

I want to create the next schema:
client—HTTPS (aws load balancer)—fargate container runninng HTTP traffic.
I want to terminate HTTPS session with load balancer istead of having expensive SSL certificates in docker container.It is possible for some redirection with aws to handle HTTPS traffic via Internet but in container service to listen for pure HTTP?

I have tried cert bot but for me it is not the right decision.

The schema I need to implement is this:
client – HTTPS – elb—HTTP – fargate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rose a ticket to the aws support and they proposed :

- Navigated to the EC2 console > Select Load Balancer > Listeners > Add Listener > Choose protocol HTTPS and port 443; in Default actions, Add Action, Redirect To "#{protocol}" and Port 80, leave remaining configuration as it is.
- Next, on the same page, in Default SSL certificate, choose the SSL certificate that I created for the Route53 domain.
- Saved!
- Navigated to the ECS console, ensured that the container defined in Task Definition is running on Port 80.
- Next, created a Cluster, created a Service in the same VPC in which my Application Load Balancer resides.
- While configuring the Service, I selected my ALB, and in the 'Container to Load Balance' section, I added the following configurations:
- Production Listener Port 443:HTTPS
- Production Listener Protocol HTTPS
- Target Group Name - Create New
- Target Group Protocol - HTTP (Since our Fargate container is listening on Port 80)
- Path Pattern /
- Evaluation order 1
- HealthCheck Path /
- Created the Service.

Answer (score -1):

@VEI It is possible. This is a good place to start

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-alb-auto-register/

Comment: those examples are for when we have https to https, it doesn't describe my problem.Maybe this is misunderstanding to clear the view i will you describe in more details. For example if you scan https://www.test.com it will display that the open port is  only 443 HTTPS traffic.But behind the https there is load balancer, behind the load balancer are docker containers with open port 80 (clear traffic).
So the https traffic will be terminated ON load balancer after that i need http traffic go to trough my container that serve http.
This is the thing that i want to create.

Comment: I was too quick with the links, sorry for that. The termination will automatically happen when you select the protocol to be http and port as 80 in the "Configure Routing" phase of creating an application load balancer. The blog here have a step by step instruction of this.
https://ifritltd.com/2018/07/02/ssl-termination-with-alb-aws-certificate-manager-and-terraform/